# using request on a raspberry pi with node.js

Tags: node.js, request, raspberry-pi, package

I am trying to use the package 'request' in a pi 3 server-project. However, the project only contains the

```
var request = require('request')'
```

line,  but it is already not working. If I start debugging it will end in Code 1. I tried to step through the process and at some point it throws the error

> out of stack

My question is has anyone set up a pi 3 with request working, and do I have to do something special if I want to use it?